# How to set a bean qualifier name at run time in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

We can set qualifier names for a bean (for  example `@Qualifier(value="myBeanQualifiedName")`   ) . but I want to know how to set a Qualifier name at run time in a `@Configuration` class.

Assume based on a application logic I want to give a name to a bean as a qualifier in a configuration file.
**EDITED:**

ConcreteBean is a child class of MyAbstractBean.

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanFactory {

    @Bean
    public MyAbstractBean getMySpecifiedBean(String condition){
        String QUALIFIER_NAME="QulifierName"+condition;
        if(//some condition here ){
        //How to set a qualifier name :QUALIFIER_NAME for this ConcreteBean instance?    
       MyAbstractBean b1= new ConcreteBean();
       b1.setService(new AnotherService1);  // and set some field values to this concrete bean
       return b1;
        }
        else  {
         MyAbstractBean b2= new ConcreteBean();
       b2.setService(new AnotherService2);  
       return b2;
        }

    }
}
```

Assume *getMySpecifiedBean()* method is called from different locations and each location need difference instances, but the type of ConcretBean(). Instances are differ each other because of the setService() method set different property values. Therefore, the b1 and b2 will do difference things with its service instance where they are used.

In my above example, based on the condition, the QUALIFIER_NAME name will be changed.Then Can we assign the prepared QUALIFIER_NAME to the qualifier name to the newly created bean? and how to get such beans with the qualifier name (qualifier name is known) ?  For example in another location,
String qalifierName="QulifierName" + preparedConditionedString;
@Autowired
@Qualified (qalifierName)

String qalifierName2="QulifierName" + preparedConditionedString2;
@Autowired
@Qualified (qalifierName2)

Also you may think what if we hard code the qualifiers.. but think what if there 20 or more instances to be created ? We have to repeat the codes.

Comment: What kind of condition are we talking about? Also, why do you care about the qualifier if you have correctly created the bean?

Comment: Have a look at ServiceLocatorFactoryBean

Comment: @geoand . Assume based on the condition, the parameter which are set to the bean can be varied. This can be like the factory pattern. Further, based on the parameter values, what the bean does can also be varied than others when the bean is in use. Therefore getting the correct bean is important.

Comment: @Débora Thanks for the info! I see what you are saying, but I still don't understand why you need to set the qualifier. From what you are showing, you are only going to be registering one `MyAbstractBean` bean so why do you need to set the qualifier?

Comment: @Qualifier is an annotation and annotations belong to a class, not an instance.  You cannot set a different qualifier name for each instance.  Where is the qualifier name used in your case?

Comment: @geoand Thank you. I updated my question. Actually this my approach is similar to the Factory Pattern. Instances are created based on the sending parameters to the method which creates instances. May be my approach is wrong to create instances like factory pattern with Spring framework.

Comment: @Débora When you mention `getMySpecifiedBean() method is called from different locations` do you mean that you are actually calling it your self?

Comment: @geoand . Yes.. is not not correct ?

Comment: @Débora Unfortunately it's not. I suggest you revise your approach, since the bean creation is supposed to be done by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for all and geoand. Your answer put me in the correct path. As Hannes mentioned first (thanks Hannes !!), I should to `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean` for my purpose.

Comment: @Débora Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my "Have a look at ServiceLocatorFactoryBean" comment:

```
public class MyBeanFactory
{
    private IServiceFactory serviceFactory;
    private IDecisionMaker decisionMaker;

    public IBean createNewInstance(final String condition)
    {
      String conditionResult = decisionMaker.decide(condition);
      return serviceFactory.getNewInstance(conditionResult);
    }

    public void setServiceFactory(final IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }
    public void setDecisionMaker(final IDecisionMaker decisionMaker)
    {
        this.decisionMaker = decisionMaker;
    }
}
```

**The `IServiceFactory` Interface**
This will allow you to map prototype beans to a decision string (core function of you question).

```
public interface IServiceFactory
{
    IBean getNewInstance(String identifier);
}
```

**The `IBean` Interface**
This will allow you to handle the returned bean (prototype) from the factory.

```
public interface IBean
{
    //TODO
}
```

**The `IDecisionMaker` Interface.**
This will make your decision making processes independed of you factory code.
An implementation takes your `condition` string and returns a property name, that will result in a IBean from the IServiceFactory implementation/configuration.

```
public interface IDecisionMaker
{
    String decide(String condition);
}
```

**The Spring xml Konfiguration**

```
<! implementations of the IBean interface -->
<bean id="myBeanRed" class="..." scope="prototype" />
<bean id="myBeanBlue"  class="..." scope="prototype" />
<bean id="myBeanGreen" class="..." scope="prototype" />

<!-- the decision maker -->
<bean id="decisionMaker" class="...">
       <!-- define your decision making here  like:
            condition(color=red)->red
            condition(color=blue)->blue
            condition(ELSE)->green
        -->
</bean>

<!-- the abstract factory -->
<bean id="myBeanServiceFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ServiceLocatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceLocatorInterface" value="...IServiceFactory "/>
    <property name="serviceMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="red">myBeanRed</prop>
            <prop key="blue">myBeanBlue</prop>
            <prop key="green">myBeanGreen</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- the factory -->
<bean id="myBeanFac" class="...MyBeanFactory" scope="singleton">
    <property name="serviceFactory" ref="myBeanServiceFactory" />
    <property name="decisionMaker" ref="decisionMaker" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I appreciate your support Hannes and thank you very much for your detailed sample.